# How to use bean in dagger 2?

Tags: javabeans, dagger-2

I've 2 packages. In Package A, There is bean

```
@Bean(name = BEAN_NAME)
    public PkgA getPkgA_Bean() {
        return new JobReasonCodesFetcherImpl(componentConfiguration.component());
    }
```

So In package B, I've dagger 2.
So how should I use this bean in package B. So that it injects PkgA through bean name ?

Can anyone please help me to understand how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think you are using Spring term instead of dagger

You want to use `@Produce` inside a module instead of `@Bean`

For using name in dager you can use `@Named`

And be careful dagger2 is using code generation instead of reflection for spring. In consequence some things can be easy to do in spring can't be done with dagger. Like classpath analysis